# Conversion of proper to improper integrals and vice versa, is the following case possible?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I recently stumbled across a particular integral which got me asking myself this:
Given a function (Smooth enough that we can play around with, and no convergence issues when integrating) $f(x)$, is there a function $g(x,T)$ satisfying:

$$ \int_0^T f(x) \, dx  = \int_0^\infty g(x,T) \, dx $$

How do we then compute $g$

Comment: This sort of doesn't quite make sense. $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is a number, while $\int_0^\infty g(x,t)\,dx$ is a function of $t$...

Comment: Ah I see, it was unclear but the upper limit is $t$.

Comment: The answer to the revised version is yes, but not for any interesting reason, or in any useful way, as far as I can see. For example, you could define $g$ by $g(x,T) = \int_0^T f$ for $0\le x\le T$, and $g(x,T)=0$ for $x>T$.

Comment: I see, took me a while to understand what you meant there. Is there any way of defining $g$ as a continuous function?

Comment: The reason it seems like there's not going to be an interesting or useful answer to your question is that there are just so many ways to define $g$. Say $\phi$ is any continuous function you want such that $\int_0^\infty\phi=1$. Define $g(x,T)=\phi(x)\int_0^T f$.

Comment: Understood. Thanks David

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28808/discussion-between-ismail-bello-and-david-c-ullrich).